# php classes and extends, variable scope confusion

Tags: php

I'm confused on how to correctly access a variable inside a parent class, that's being set inside a child class.

Say we have the parent class (as $user):

```
class user
{
   public $details = [];
}
```

Child class (as $login):

```
class login extends user
{
    function do_login()
    {
        // something before here to grab their details from the DB
        $this->details = $grabbed_user_details;
    }
}
```

Then in the script that calls everything I was hoping to do something like:

```
$user = new user();
$login = new login();
$login->do_login();
$user->details['username'];
```

However, "details" seems to be empty. Am I going completely the wrong way about this? Don't think I quite understand scope yet.

Comment: you haven't stored anything in `$user` but in `$login`. Try `$login->details['username']`

Comment: That's where I'm confused, I thought by setting it in the login class, since it extends the user class, it would set it for $user?

Comment: Nope, the login is an user plus the extensions you made in the login class.

Comment: The __class__ `login` extends the __class__ `user`.... you instantiate class `login`, and the (public) properties of both login and user are available to that instance; but you don't have separate instances of each that are somehow magically connected

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = new user();
```

This creates a new object with it's `details` property being an empty array.

```
$login = new login();
```

This creates a second new object with *it's own* `details` property being an empty array.

```
$login->do_login();
```

This will populate the `$login` object's `details` array.  The `$user` object's `details` remains empty.

To get to the array that's populated:

```
$login->details['username'];
```